# org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection issue

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
FAILED: output
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V from class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:304)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:156)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:124)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:559)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:112)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:218)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
    at com.qa.testcases.WindowHandler.output(WindowHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

enter code here

This read data from excel sheet code:

```
     package com.qa.testcases;

     import java.util.*;
     import java.io.*;
     import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
     import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
     import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
     import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
     import org.openqa.selenium.By;
     import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
     import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
     import org.testng.annotations.Test;

     public class WindowHandler {
     @Test
     public void output() throws Exception
     {
        try
        {File file = new File("E:\\demo.xlsx");
            FileInputStream src = new FileInputStream(file);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(src);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

     int rowcount= sheet.getLastRowNum();
     System.out.println(rowcount+1);
     for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++) {
     String data=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
     System.out.println(data);
      }
     workbook.close();

        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     }
```

and below are the dependency  -

```
<properties> <poi.version>3.13</poi.version> </properties> 
<dependencies>
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
<artifactId>poi</artifactId> 
<version>${poi.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
<artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId> 
<version>${poi.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> 
<version>${poi.version}</version> 
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please post more description about the issue like how you encountered etc. Would be useful in resolving the issue

Comment: <properties>
    <poi.version>3.13</poi.version>
  </properties>
   <dependencies><dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency></dependencies>

Comment: PackageRelationShip error comes when you have POI jars having different version.
In your case dependencies look fine. Can you please try doing "maven clean" and run your test again , if that does not work try latest POI version.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the poi jars here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/4.1.0 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.0

For these two observe the dependent jars also. use required jars along with dependent jars with specified versions.